# Access Linux Audio Capture Stream (Raspberry Pi 3)

Tags: c, linux, audio, raspberry-pi, signal-processing

I'd like to make system-wide application like following in Raspberry Pi 3.

1. USB Mic Input
2. Audio Input Stream Buffer (PCM raw data)
3. Perform Realtime Signal Processing with my own code (e.g. Noise Cancellation) needs under 20ms latency
4. Overwrite *3's output to Audio Input Stream Buffer (same buffer with 2.)
5. Sensory or Kitt.AI (hotword detection engine)

I have found linux audio APIs like ALSA, PortAudio, Jack, PulseAudio, LADSPA plugin (make a static object library), etc.

Also ordered a book [Linux Sound Programming](http://www.apress.com/br/book/9781484224953).
And have tried some examples but no advance yet.
(Simple ALSA example have failed because CAPTURING AUDIO BUFFER is already used by hotword detection engine)

I am new to linux and some methods like JackAudio, LADSPA seem so sophisticated to me.

I wonder if is it possible and which method is better.

Comment: In a very few words, yes, it is possible to perform this kind of operation but you seem far from being able to do what you want at this point (no disrespect intended) from what you are saying. To me, what could be a decent solution if you want a permanent processing is to write a module for PulseAudio and link it to it at daemon startup [link](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/Developer/Modules/). Keep reading your book and it might become clearer (might be a good idea to read some stuff about Linux itself).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.